# BigQuery comma delimited string evaluation

Tags: sql, regex, string, google-bigquery

I am using BigQuery and I'm trying to parse a comma delimited string to find specific numbers within it.

Example table as below

```
|--------|-----------------------------------------------------------|
| userID | sequence                                                  |
|--------|-----------------------------------------------------------|
| 123abc | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8                                           |                                          
|--------|-----------------------------------------------------------|
| 456bcd | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11                                   |
|--------|-----------------------------------------------------------|
| 789def | 1,2,3,4                                                   |
|--------|-----------------------------------------------------------|
```

I need to create a CASE statement where each value of the string 'sequence' is evaluated as per the following logic and the result outputted to its own column.

```
SELECT userID
,sequence
,CASE WHEN sequence CONTAINS '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS action1 
,CASE WHEN sequence CONTAINS '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS action2 
,CASE WHEN sequence CONTAINS '3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as action3
....
,CASE WHEN sequence CONTAINS '9' AND '11' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as action10
```

This would produce the following output.

```
|--------|-------------------------|-------|-------|-------|---------|
| userID | sequence                |action1|action2|action3|action10 |
|--------|-------------------------|-------|-------|-------|---------|
| 123abc | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8         |   1   |   1   |   1   |    0    |                                          
|--------|-------------------------|-------|-------|-------|---------|
| 456bcd | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 |   1   |   1   |   1   |    1    |
|--------|-------------------------|-------|-------|-------|---------|
| 789def | 1,2                     |   1   |   1   |   0   |    0    |
|--------|-------------------------|-------|-------|-------|---------|
```

Please not the last CASE WHEN statement is very important as I need to account for this very specific combination of string values as its own unique action.

I believe this would be achievable in SQL Server using something like:

```
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('1', 'sequence')>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as action1
,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('2', 'sequence')>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as action2
,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('3', 'sequence')>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as action3
...
,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('9', 'sequence')>0 AND CHARINDEX('11', 'sequence')>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as action10
```

However I cannot find an equivalent function in BigQuery that would achieve the same result and my attempts at REGEX have also fallen short.

I'd be very grateful for some guidance here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see direction below (for BigQuery Standard SQL)

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '123abc' userID, '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8' sequence UNION ALL
  SELECT '456bcd', '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11' UNION ALL
  SELECT '789def', '1,2' 
)
SELECT userID, 
  IF((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(sequence)) value WHERE value = '1' ) > 0, 1, 0)  action1,
  IF((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(sequence)) value WHERE value = '2' ) > 0, 1, 0)  action2,
  IF((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(sequence)) value WHERE value = '3' ) > 0, 1, 0)  action3,
  IF((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(sequence)) value WHERE value = '4' ) > 0, 1, 0)  action4,
  IF((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(sequence)) value WHERE value = '5' ) > 0, 1, 0)  action5,
  IF((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(sequence)) value WHERE value = '6' ) > 0, 1, 0)  action6,
  IF((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(sequence)) value WHERE value = '7' ) > 0, 1, 0)  action7,
  IF((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(sequence)) value WHERE value = '8' ) > 0, 1, 0)  action8,
  IF((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(sequence)) value WHERE value = '9' ) > 0, 1, 0)  action9,
  IF((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(sequence)) value WHERE value IN ('10', '11' )) > 0, 1, 0)  action10
FROM `project.dataset.table`
-- ORDER BY userID
```

this will give you something like below

```sql
Row userID  action1 action2 action3 action4 action5 action6 action7 action8 action9 action10     
1   123abc  1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       0       0    
2   456bcd  1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1    
3   789def  1       1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
```

it is simplified  - but gives you `some guidance` as you asked for :o)

See below idea for refactoring (which is endless process usually) so it is less verbose at least

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '123abc' userID, '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8' sequence UNION ALL
  SELECT '456bcd', '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11' UNION ALL
  SELECT '789def', '1,2' 
)
SELECT userID, 
  IF('1' IN UNNEST(SPLIT(sequence)), 1, 0) AS action1,
  IF('2' IN UNNEST(SPLIT(sequence)), 1, 0) AS action2,
  IF('3' IN UNNEST(SPLIT(sequence)), 1, 0) AS action3,
  IF('4' IN UNNEST(SPLIT(sequence)), 1, 0) AS action4,
  IF('5' IN UNNEST(SPLIT(sequence)), 1, 0) AS action5,
  IF('6' IN UNNEST(SPLIT(sequence)), 1, 0) AS action6,
  IF('7' IN UNNEST(SPLIT(sequence)), 1, 0) AS action7,
  IF('8' IN UNNEST(SPLIT(sequence)), 1, 0) AS action8,
  IF('9' IN UNNEST(SPLIT(sequence)), 1, 0) AS action9,
  IF((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(sequence)) value WHERE value IN ('10', '11' )) > 0, 1, 0)  action10
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

> Update to address your comments about UNION ALL

Above is using dummy data from your question just so you can test, play with it  - meantime the solution actually is

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT userID, 
  IF('1' IN UNNEST(SPLIT(sequence)), 1, 0) AS action1,
  IF('2' IN UNNEST(SPLIT(sequence)), 1, 0) AS action2,
  IF('3' IN UNNEST(SPLIT(sequence)), 1, 0) AS action3,
  IF('4' IN UNNEST(SPLIT(sequence)), 1, 0) AS action4,
  IF('5' IN UNNEST(SPLIT(sequence)), 1, 0) AS action5,
  IF('6' IN UNNEST(SPLIT(sequence)), 1, 0) AS action6,
  IF('7' IN UNNEST(SPLIT(sequence)), 1, 0) AS action7,
  IF('8' IN UNNEST(SPLIT(sequence)), 1, 0) AS action8,
  IF('9' IN UNNEST(SPLIT(sequence)), 1, 0) AS action9,
  IF((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(sequence)) value WHERE value IN ('10', '11' )) > 0, 1, 0)  action10
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Comment: Thanks @Mikhail Berlyant this is a good solution although not ideal because I have many, many rows of userID so I would much prefer to use a solution which did not require and extensive UNION ALL list

Comment: if you are referencing to UNION ALL within WITH clouse  - thi sis not a part of solution but rather the way to use sample data - see update in few sec in my answer!

Comment: See update in answer  - please check and let me know if still confusion! - and obviously you should use your project and dataset and table names instead of `project.dataset.table`

Comment: Thanks @Mikhail Berlyant - It had been a long day so I misinterpreted your answer however it makes complete sense.
I had to amend the CASE statement to the following:
`,IF((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(sequence)) value WHERE value IN ('10') AND value NOT IN ('11'))>0, 1, 0)  AS action10` 
and 
`,IF((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(sequence)) value WHERE value IN ('10') AND value IN ('11')) > 0, 1, 0)  AS action11`
because otherwise the `IN('','')` is essentially an `OR` which produces incorrect results but your logic is clear and your methodology is perfectly intelligible. Thanks!